If $F$ attains its local minimum at $x=0$ then $F(x)-F(0)\geq\xi x$

Let $F:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be the convex mapping. Prove that
there exists derivatives $F'(0+), F'(0-)$ and if $F$ attains its local minimum at $x=0$ then $$F(x)-F(0)\geq \xi x,\quad\forall x,\xi\in[F'(0-),F'(0+)].$$

I have proved that there exists $F'(0+), F'(0-)$. I'm stuck at proving if $F$ attains its local minimum at $x=0$ then $F(x)-F(0)\geq \xi x,\quad\forall x,\xi\in[F'(0-),F'(0+)].$ I know that if $F$ attains its local minimum at $x=0$ then $F(x)>F(0)\quad\forall V(0,\epsilon)\setminus\{0\}$, where $V(0,\epsilon)$ is the neighborhood of $0$. Could someone help me to deal with the rest of the problem? Thanks in advance!

For $x_1<x_2<x_3$ the convexity implies that
$${f(x_3)-f(x_2)\over x_3-x_2}\ge {f(x_2)-f(x_1)\over x_2-x_1}$$ which means that the inclination of graph is nondecreasing. Let $x>0$ then substituting $x_1=0, x_2=u$ and $x_3=x$ gives
$${f(x)-f(u)\over x-u}\ge {f(u)-f(0)\over u} $$ Letting $u\to 0^+$ yields
$${f(x)-f(0)\over x}\ge f'_+(0)\implies f(x)-f(0)\ge xf_+'(0)\quad (*)$$
Similarly substituting $x_1=u, $ $x_2=0$ and $x_3=x$ gives
$${f(x)-f(0)\over x}\ge {f(0)-f(u)\over -u} $$ Letting $u\to 0^-$ gives
$${f(x)-f(0)\over x}\ge f'_-(0) \implies f(x)-f(0)\ge xf'_-(0) \quad (**)$$ Combining $(*)$ and $(**)$ gives the conclusion for $x>0.$
Concerning $x<0$ we may either adjust the above reasoning or consider the convex function $g(x):=f(-x).$ The conclusion for $g$ and $x>0$ is equivalent to that for $f$ and $x<0.$
